# How to put together an options object in flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I have the following javascript:

```
  if(i==1&&$('#ln').val()=='true')
    ops={
      xaxis: {show:false},
      yaxis: {show:false,
              transform: function (v) { return -v; },
              inverseTransform: function (v) { return -v; }}}
  else ops={xaxis: {show:false}, yaxis: {show:false}};
  $.plot($(gr), pdat,ops);
```

When I tried to make a string of `ops` I got errors on parsing it. I suppose it's because of the functions. 
How can I put together the options so I can add other options according to different conditions? In the example the idea is to avoid repeating `xaxis: {show:false}, yaxis: {show:false}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can populate the `ops` object with the common properties and then add others in your if statement:

```
  // initalize ops with common properties
  var ops = {
      xaxis: {show: false},
      yaxis: {show: false}
  };
  if (i == 1 && $('#ln').val() == 'true') {
      ops.yaxis.transform = function (v) { return -v; };
      ops.yaxis.inverseTransform = function (v) { return -v; };
  }
  $.plot($(gr), pdat, ops);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a more complicated scenario, I'd recommend jquery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method:

```
var ops = {
  xaxis: {show: false},
  yaxis: {show: false}
};
if (i == 1 && $('#ln').val() == 'true') {
    $.extend(true, ops, {
      yaxis: {
         transform: function (v) { return -v; },
         inverseTransform: function (v) { return -v; }
      }
    });
}
```

Ops is now:

```
{
  "xaxis":{
     "show":false
   },
  "yaxis":{
     "show":false,
     "transform": function (v) { return -v; },
     "inverseTransform": function (v) { return -v; }
   }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't tagged jQuery.

Comment: Flot requires jQuery so that is not an issue.